# Send Skype messages from web

Tags: c#, skype

Is it possible to send skype messages from web, without using the skype desktop application.
Ex: User inputs his skype username, destination skype username and message, then probably there would be authorization request from skype, he'd enter his username and password, and then message would be sent to the recipient.

I also wander if it is possible to somehow send message to those who have chosen "Allow IMs from people in my contact list only", and sender isnt in recipients contact list.

If anyone knows, please write here or link the resources where i can find information about this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "... also wander if it is possible to somehow send message to those who have chosen "Allow IMs from people in my contact list only", and sender isnt in recipients contact list."

You are not writing spam, are you?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this looks promising:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/skypecontrolapicsharp.aspx

The skype developer blog also has an example:

http://blogs.skype.com/developer/2006/12/c_example_project_for_skype4co.html

Comment: Both of the examlpes are using Skype clients, I need to do it without that. If that is possible at all.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.First though your Skype application  has to be opened.
Then in your ASP.NET project simply import the Skype4ComLib.dll

```
using Skype4ComLib;
```

then send a message to a recipient  using such:

```
    Skype snd = new Skype();  
    snd.SendMessage("receiversuserid", Message)
```

Comment: Your suggestion is exactly what the previous answer (from 5 years ago) had and the OP rejected it because Skype4Com requires you to have skype installed which the OP said he can not do in his web server enviorment. Also from what I have read Skype4Com stoped working in 2014 when Microsoft shut off the API, does it still work?